# Rails Solr Sunspot integration with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sunspot

Is there a way to integrate ActiveRecord syntax and methods with the `results` object given by Sunspot?

For example, `Post.where(...).search{fulltext 'pizza'}.results` does not filter the results by my `where(...)` clause, and `Post.search{fulltext 'pizza'}.results.where(...)` returns `NoMethodError: undefined method 'where' for #<Sunspot::Search::PaginatedCollection:0x007fe9b388bd88>`

Without indexing everything, is there a way to coordinate my Sunspot search with an ActiveRecord query? Some of my AR filters are too complex to simply rewrite in Sunspot's preferred syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to index the fields for your conditional statement.

```
Post.search do
 with(:blog_id, 1)
 fulltext("pizza")
end
```

A messy solution is to add a conditional statement as you go through the results.

```
search.each_hit_with_result do |hit, result|
  if result.post_id == 2
    #stuff
  end
end
```

You can also create a conditional index.
http://mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/19-conditional-indexing-with-sunspot